# kill php process on host

Tags: php, apache, dos, cpanel

I'm running `while(TRUE)` php script on my host,that I think it will be ended by closing browser, I run it on my `Cpanel` web hosting to learning DoS attack. Now I close browser but it continuing attack.
How can I kill it in `Cpanel` ,only with `Cpanel` permission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just have a host or you are just a reseller, you can't. You need to root permission to do this.

If you did run the script on browser, PHP or Apache should kill the process after the maximum execution time.

Default maximum execution time is 30 seconds for PHP and -I guess- 150 secons for Apache.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to restart apache from CPanel, I think it's the only way:

http://forums.cpanel.net/f5/restarting-apache-60364.html

Comment: Are you sure just by restarting apache will help?

Comment: yes, PHP usually is compiled as apache module, so it sits inside apache process.

Comment: but I don't have apache access.

Comment: If you don't have access, then you should probably call your hosting company and ask them. Normally process should terminate in 30 seconds, if they don't put that restriction, it's their fault.

Comment: lol ... bold assumption ... Only OP will knew (provided he has the information)

Comment: what I'm saying - if he does not have permissions to restart apache, and the process don't die on it's own, then there is nothing he can do on his own. Not through CPanel. Restarting Apache from Unix Shell is a whole new question.